# JVM tuning on Amazon EC2

Tags: tomcat, jvm, amazon-ec2, performance

We will be deploying a production application to Amazon EC2 very shortly.  Initially, we'll just be using a "small" instance, but have plans to scale up not long afterwards.  My question is, has any investigation been done on JVM tuning for the EC2 environment?  Are there any specific changes that we should make to our JVM parameters to compensate for quirks/characteristics of Amazon EC2?  Or, do the normal tuning methodologies apply here as they would in a physical environment?

Our application will be deployed on Tomcat 6.x.  It is built using JBoss Seam 2.2.x, and uses PostgreSQL 8.x as the backend database.  Any advice you can give is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do nothing specific to EC2 instancs (and can't), just normal JVM- and GC-tuning.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference this. it did JVM tuning over EC2 instance. 
I used c1.medium instance for Apache Tomcat. 
Cheers

http://javamaster.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/apache-tomcat-tuning-guide/